# When I use the magic Wand Tool to select and crop an image, a white background is cropped behind it even though I'm not selecting any white background

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Looks like this:

[image: tshirt image]

I only select the black tshirt, click crop but the white background is still there?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Your question is a bit confusing. Not sure what you mean by "crop".  Cropping is when you trim an image down to size. What you are doing is not called cropping. Looks like you are trying to make a selection, or perhaps invert a selection. Is that right?

Answer (score 3):

You can only **crop** to a **rectangle**. It is not possible to "crop" an image to a non-rectangular shape.

Rather than "crop" you may want to click the t-shirt, then **invert the selection** (Menu: Select > Inverse) and then hit the Delete key, or add a **Layer Mask**.